# Google closure compiler does not report divide-by-zero

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, divide-by-zero

I have run google closure compiler for next:

```
alert(1 / 0);
```

with command:

```
java -jar node_modules\google-closure-compiler\compiler.jar --warning_level=VERBOSE test.js
```

and it does not report anything. I expected it says something about devide-by-zero because the reference(https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/error-ref) mentions about

> `JSC_DIVIDE_BY_0_ERROR`:
>
> Divide by 0
>
> This error means that you an arithmetical division expression with a denominator of 0. Dividing by zero at runtime produces a runtime error.

I've also tested the example code for `JSC_BITWISE_OPERAND_OUT_OF_RANGE`:

```
var y = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2 >> 2;
```

and in this case, google closure compiler exactly point out the problem.

```
test.js:2: WARNING - Operand out of range, bitwise operation will lose information: NUMBER 2.147483648E9 2 [length: 22] [source_file: test.js]
var y = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2 >> 2;
        ^
```

How can I get `JSC_DIVIDE_BY_0_ERROR` for the top source code?

Comment: *"Dividing by zero at runtime produces a runtime error."* - No it doesn't, in JavaScript a division by zero produces the value `Infinity`. (Which may be a *logic* error in your algorithm, but it's not a runtime error in the sense of an exception.)

Comment: Are you saying that the description in reference of closure compiler is not right? Anyway, I don't care what happens in runtime here. I want to check it statically using closure compiler.

Comment: If it is intended as a desription of how JavaScript works then it is definitely wrong, but I don't know how those Closure Compiler options are supposed to work. (Regarding checking for division by zero statically, obviously you can only do that for constants because if your code says `1 / x` the compiler can't tell what `x` will be at runtime, but I guess you know that.)

Comment: @nnnnn Except when dividing zero by zero, which gives `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSC_DIVIDE_BY_0_ERROR` error no longer exists in the compiler source code, you can search for it at https://github.com/google/closure-compiler.  So that error check must have been removed.

The Closure Compiler documentation is currently a bit out of date and scattered among various pages.

Comment: It was deleted in March 2011